# Places API returning NOT_FOUND

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places

Since this morning the Places API has returned NOT_FOUND results for every single place ID we've tried searching for.

We regularly query the API to check details & it has been running fine for over a year but today it's fell over and only returns NOT_FOUND, for over 300 different place ids.

Is there a current issue with the API?

Comment: It seems that pulling place id data for service businesses no longer works? Why?

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Google Cloud support today about this because it still hasn't changed.

Yes they no longer support Service area businesses in the Places API. Here is their response:

> Thank you for contacting Maps Platform Technical Support. My name is Ana and I'm here to assist you.
>
> Places API mission is to enable developers to help users find relevant places to visit. Since Service Area Businesses are not places users can visit, they do not belong in the Places API. That is the reason why you cannot search it in Places API and it is an intended behavior.
>
> Business owners can fix this via MyBusiness IF they have a brick-and-mortar shop
>       (a shop someone can visit on the streets).

I find this shocking that developers are unable to pull out information about any ACTIVE business on Google. I have responded with my own views but as expected Google will not change their stance.

> Well that is very confusing to customers. You (rightly so) allow local listings to be setup as service area businesses. Why should only brick and mortar shops be allowed to utilise the Place API? That’s separating the market for businesses to advertise properly and surely is not legal.
>
> Regardless of if you agree about service area businesses not being allowed to be shown on Maps – there is no reason that an ACTIVE business should not return details through a Development API which has no public facing impact. It is stifling the support agencies and businesses can provide to its customers.
>
> We're denied access to the Google My Business API and then resort to pulling out data via the Places API and now we can no longer do that.
>
> You should at the very least provide some kind of development data for ANY business that is available on Google, whether that be via the Places API or not – business owners should have a right to pull out data about their own business at any time.
>
> Please forward this to the GMB team.